# Menu button works just ONE time

Tags: android, menu

I want to show a Menu when click a specific image :

```
popup_but = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
popup_but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showmen();
    }
});
```

And the menu :

```
public void showmen() {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(First.this, popup_but);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) 
            {
                case R.id.men1:
                    //do something
                return true;
                case R.id.men5:
                    finish();
                 return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

It. works. now i want to do the same when click the hardware menu button. so i use this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    showmen();
}
```

**The problem is here : when menu button clicked it just show menu for the FIRST time**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29):

> On Android 2.3.x and lower, the system calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>   each time the user opens the options menu (presses the Menu button).
>
> On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be
>   open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event
>   occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call
>   invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu().

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called every time the hardware menu button is clicked, and if it returns `true` each time. What I do is, style the menu items using XML and then inflate the XML inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()` . Every time I click the hardware menu, the menu is inflated from XML. `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` is only for when you want to change the menu items during the lifecycle of the app. The problem, I think is in your implementation of `showmen()`. I think the `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` is called only the first time, not every time.